# Can you copyright reproduced information by open government licence?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom

I want to use some of the information from one website, but that website has a copyright. The source of the information is under Open Government License"

I have a few questions regarding the licence 
"Life in the United Kingdom: A Guide for New Residents (ISBN 978-0-11-341340-9)"

**That website has a policy:**

"All chapters from the study materials are crown copyright and have been reproduced from the government publication Life in the United Kingdom: A Guide for New Residents (ISBN 978-0-11-341340-9). This material has been reproduced with the permission of The National Archives under the Open Government License."

Open government licence
http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/

Does it mean that all the information that has been "reproduced" from books follow their copyright?

Can you copyright reproduced information by open government licence?

I just want to know can I use the information from that website and just mention  Open Government License and "Life in the United Kingdom: A Guide for New Residents (ISBN 978-0-11-341340-9)"'

Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: "Can I use it?" and "Can I copyright it?" are completely different questions.

Comment: Yes, both questions are related to each other. It will be nice to hear the answers to both questions.